# Where can I find the C++11 standard papers?

Tags: c++, c++11

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Where do I find the current C or C++ standard documents?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/81656/where-do-i-find-the-current-c-or-c-standard-documents)

Where can I find the full C++11 standard? I know features of it are floating around the internet but I can't seem to find the document itself.

Answer (score 47, accepted):

You can get the full, final standard directly from the [ISO](http://www.iso.org/iso/iso_catalogue/catalogue_tc/catalogue_detail.htm?csnumber=50372), or some [national bodies](http://webstore.ansi.org/RecordDetail.aspx?sku=ISO/IEC%2014882:2011).

You probably don't want to get in a hurry though. The ANSI (for one) normally re-publishes an official version with identical technical material -- basically the only change is saying "ANSI/ISO" on the the title page instead of just "ISO". At least for past versions, however, the price has been *much* more reasonable (~$30US instead of ~$400US).

Edit: As expected, [the standard](http://webstore.ansi.org/RecordDetail.aspx?sku=INCITS/ISO/IEC%2014882-2012) is now available for $30US.

Comment: Good suggestion to wait for the ANSI or other publisher's "version".  In the meantime, you may make do with the latest draft standard: N3242 http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2011/n3242.pdf

Comment: @mjv : The latest _freely available_ draft standard -- N3290 is the actual latest.

Comment: @ildjarn: Except that it isn't freely available.

Comment: @mjv: ANSI already has [the spec available for purchase](http://webstore.ansi.org/RecordDetail.aspx?sku=ISO%2fIEC+14882%3a2011), but even they charge $400 for it.

Comment: @ildjarn: Sorry; I misread what you said.

Comment: @ildjarn: better yet, thanks!  N3290's gotta be darn close to the "real thing"...

Comment: @mjv : Sorry, I wasn't clear. N3290 is the latest, but isn't freely available any more; I just meant to say that N3242 isn't the latest, but is the latest that is freely available.

Comment: @ildjarn: thank you for clarifying. I was right in directing users who seek to save a bit of money till prices come down, towards N3242 which is the latest _freely_ available draft.  They should however be aware that this is _not_ the latest draft, as N3290 came after but isn't free.

Comment: @mjv: N3290 came after, and was free when it was available, but they've since removed (at least the links to) it from the committee web site, so I don't believe it's (legally) available at all any more.

Comment: The linked ANSI page is very confusing.  The title of the page is "INCITS/ISO/IEC 14882-2012" but the title of the document is "ISO/IEC 14882:2011."

Comment: @JamesMcNellis: It was adopted as an ISO standard in late 2011. The ISO standard was then adopted (without changes, even to the title page) as an INCITS standard in early 2012. Though the relationship between INCITS and ANSI is hard to nail down, I believe that means it's also basically adopted as an ANSI standard.

Comment: One difference is the drafts include an index with links that you can click on, while the $30 ANSI PDF does not.  Extremely irritating.

Comment: I think it's absolutely atrocious that one has to shell out that much money to be able to read the standard of a language that claims to be open-standard.

Comment: @antred: IMO, it's utterly irrelevant. Even though I own a legal copy of the standard, I almost never use it. I almost always use the first draft that followed the standard, because it has some typos and such fixed, most internal references are clickable links (which they aren't in the real standard). You also seem to misunderstand what "open" means. It's not about the cost of the standard. It's about anybody being able to join the committee and shape the standard (unlike, say, Java, where Oracle is in complete control, so if you disagree with them, you just lose).

Answer (score 33):

If you don't really need and can't afford to shell out the money for the real thing, you can make do with the latest publicly available draft: [N3242](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2011/n3242.pdf).

Comment: are there any knows differences between this and the real version?

Comment: @Dani any differences should be minor.

Comment: @Dani The c++ chat insisted it was a 400 Euro front page.

Comment: @Dani noexcept is mostly missing in N3242.

Comment: It seems that N3485 is also available and downloadable by poor who can't pay (I have not verified the quality).

Comment: @sircolinton the most recent version of what? That document is dated 2013-05-15; it's clearly a C++14 draft. The latest publicly available C++11 draft is N3242, as I mentioned. The latest C++11 draft is N3290, which is not publicly available, as it became the final standard document (N3291). The latest draft with C++11-only changes is N3337, which has the same contents as the standard plus editorial changes. Everything after is a C++14 draft.

Comment: @R.MartinhoFernandes ah right, you're right. Deleted my comment so as not to mislead.

Answer (score 7):

IMO [cppreference.com](http://en.cppreference.com/w/)  can be a free alternative to buying the actual standard.

Answer (score 3):

The standard is available from the [ISO website](http://www.iso.org/iso/iso_catalogue/catalogue_tc/catalogue_detail.htm?csnumber=50372) for ~$400 or so.

Comment: All the people that work on gcc payed $400?

Comment: @Dani: Doubtful. Many have probably worked from (freely available) drafts, at least for the last few years. Many will probably continue to work from one of the last drafts (e.g., N3242 or N3290).

Comment: @Dani - the final standard was only published 2 weeks ago or so, compiler writers have been working against published drafts (available on open-std as linked by mjv in a comment to Jerry Coffin's answer). For C++03, the standard was (and is) available for $30 from ANSI, but the C++11 standard is still super expensive.

Answer (score 1):

It's an ISO standard, which you can purchase here: http://www.iso.org/iso/iso_catalogue/catalogue_tc/catalogue_detail.htm?csnumber=50372