# Where to find C++11 reference paper/digital, and a book reference

Tags: c++, reference, c++11

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Where is the c++11 standard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7747069/where-is-the-c11-standard)

I am looking to buy/download a few things.  First I want both a digital copy and paper copy of the official c++11 reference.

Also I would like a book that is a summation of the reference that focuses on things like commonly used c/c++ functions and the STL, something more accessible than the official reference itself.  Also would be great for both paper and digital versions.  I don't need a beginners book, just a reference.  This one is probably going to be opinionated so feel free to say which one you like.

Comment: SO's [Definitive C++ Book List](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list) may be a reasonable start. True references on C++11 are still mostly in progress.

Comment: By "official C++ reference", do you mean the Standard?  Nothing else is official in any sense of the word.

Comment: Yes I mean the standard as the first thing.  But also the second thing is a reference.

Comment: @EddiV223 - you could look too at http://distrowatch.com - sometimes there are running little ads for to get a tutorial or e-book free - then you only need to complete a form with your e-mail address (humblesome) - but in the end you have then a complete e-book ... when am not wrong there recently was even an c++11-book and c++14 (is currently under development for windows only like C#, whatever should turn out of it for windows ...) :-)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Nicolai Josuttis updated his book [The C++ Standard Library](http://www.cppstdlib.com/) for C++11 in April 2012. Specifically, it covers the following aspects:

- Concurrency
- Fractional arithmetic
- Clocks and Timers
- Random numbers and distributions
- New smart pointers
- Regular expressions
- New STL containers, such as arrays, forward lists, and unordered containers
- New STL algorithms
- Tuples
- Type traits and type utilities

It also covers the following new C++11 language elements:

- Lambdas
- Range-based for loops
- Move semantics
- Variadic templates.

Josuttis also gave [an interview about his new book](http://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=1846582&WT.mc_id=IT_NL_Content_2012_3_7&rll=1).

Answer (score 5):

There are plenty of great books on the STL, there is a giant list available on [Amazon](http://www.amazon.com/Essential-C-and-STL-books/lm/2YJO15RIJZW96). Some of the most popular ones for STL are

- [Effective STL: 50 Specific Ways to Improve Your Use of the Standard Template Library](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0201749629)
- [The C++ Standard Library: A Tutorial and Reference](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0201379260) .

For C++ 11, there are plenty of locations for references, such as

- [The Biggest Changes in C++11 (and Why You Should Care)](http://www.softwarequalityconnection.com/2011/06/the-biggest-changes-in-c11-and-why-you-should-care/)
- [C++ 11](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C++11)
- [C++ reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp) (This has more than C++11, but the C++11
  ones are tagged as such and easy to notice.

Comment: cppreference has a couple of off-line options (e.g. an HTML book), if you are looking for something like that.  No PDF version unfortunately.  You might also enjoy a cppreference mug, to use while curled up with the reference.

Answer (score 3):

[N3242](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2011/n3242.pdf) from the [February 2011 papers](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2011/) is the closest you can get to a freely-available copy of the "official" C++11 standard ...

Comment: @bames53: n3337 is the first post-C++11 standard paper.

Comment: @josephthomas Yes, and it differs from the standard only in editorial corrections.