# Is it compatible to use -ansi and -std=c++0x flags for g++ simultaneously

Tags: gcc, c++11, g++, c++98

I found that in one of our projects we use compile command like the following:

```
g++ -ansi -std=c++0x ...
```

Is it right way to use simultaneously both flags `-ansi` and `-std=c++0x`?

I read man for gcc and it looks like we have to choose only one flag. What do you think?

Comment: Well, what happens if you do that?

Comment: @filmor , Nothing) I mean that we get compilation log without any issues and also binary file works quite fine. But only fact that we use both flags looks strange for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

GCC documentation says

> -ansi
>       In C mode, this is equivalent to -std=c90. In C++ mode, it is equivalent to -std=c++98.

So, this is

```
g++ -ansi -std=c++0x ...
```

equivalent to

```
g++ -std=c++98 -std=c++0x ...
```

When you compile it with

```
g++ -ansi -std=c++0x ...
```

I believe, it's equivalent to not specifying `-ansi` at all, due to the command line parsing which usually takes the *last* argument for a given parameter. This is speculation though. But I tested with a simple program:

```
#include<iostream>

constexpr int value() {return 42;}

int main(void)
{
std::cout<<value()<<std::endl;
}
```

This program can't compile in C++98 as `constexpr` was introduced in C++11. But it compiles fine with both:

```
g++ -ansi -std=c++11 test.cpp
```

and

```
g++ -ansi -std=c++98 -std=c++11 t.cpp
```

---

But fails with both:

```
g++ -ansi -std=c++11 -ansi test.cpp
```

and

```
g++ -ansi -std=c++11 -std=c++98 t.cpp
```

Giving the errors:

```
 error: ‘constexpr’ does not name a type
 note: C++11 ‘constexpr’ only available with -std=c++11 or -std=gnu++11
```

This suggests whatever the specified as the *last* `-std` is only one effective and you might as well remove the `-ansi`.

Answer (score 0):

If you use `-std=c++0x` (which became `-std=c++11` since gcc 4.7), using `-ansi` is superfluous. See also [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7747069/where-can-i-find-the-c11-standard-papers)

Answer (score 0):

The options are mutually exclusive, since they both set the standard (or dialect) of the language which the compiler should use for the compilation. Quoting [GCC docs](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.8.0/gcc/C-Dialect-Options.html):

> ```
> -ansi
> ```
>
> In C mode, this is equivalent to `-std=c90`. In C++ mode, it is equivalent to `-std=c++98`.

So you're basically doing this:

```
gcc -std=c++98 -std=c++0x ...
```

I believe later options trump earlier options on the GCC command line, so the net effect is compiling in C++0x mode.

Comment: I think so too. Do you think that this is bad practice and I should remove `-ansi` option?

Comment: @zubactik Yes, I think you should remove it, it adds nothing but confusion.

Answer (score 0):

From [GCC: standards](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Standards.html)/ C++ language.

> GCC implements the majority of C++98 (export is a notable exception) and most of the changes in C++03. To select this standard in GCC, use one of the options -ansi, -std=c++98, or -std=c++03;

If I understand it correctly, `-ansi`, `-std=c++98`, and `-std=c++03` can be used interchangeably. Specifically, it doesn't make sense to use `-ansi` and `-std=c++11` simultaneously.