# c++ boost interprocess invalid string stored in vector

Tags: c++, boost, shared-memory, interprocess, boost-interprocess

Why string stored in variable `vectorOfStrings` at third place received as `"bbbb\xFF\xFF\xFF\xC0"` is not presented as value `"bbbb"` use in `push_back` method?

Boost version: `1.78`

Required system: `GNU/linux` (any distribution, tested on ubuntu)

Compile command: `clang++ main.cpp -g -lrt -pthread -o test` (or use g++)

Code:

```
#include <bits/char_traits.h>
#include <boost/interprocess/allocators/allocator.hpp>
#include <boost/interprocess/containers/string.hpp>
#include <boost/interprocess/containers/vector.hpp>
#include <boost/interprocess/managed_shared_memory.hpp>
#include <cstring>

namespace Interprocess = boost::interprocess;
template <class T>
using ShmAllocator = Interprocess::allocator<T, Interprocess::managed_shared_memory::segment_manager>;
using ShmString = Interprocess::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, ShmAllocator<char>>;

int main()
{
    const auto memoryName = "test_memory";
    Interprocess::shared_memory_object::remove(memoryName);
    auto shm = Interprocess::managed_shared_memory(Interprocess::create_only, memoryName, 1024 * 1024);

    auto stringAllocator = ShmAllocator<ShmString>(shm.get_segment_manager());
    auto intAllocator = ShmAllocator<int>(shm.get_segment_manager());

    auto vectorOfStrings = Interprocess::vector<ShmString, ShmAllocator<ShmString>>(stringAllocator);
    auto vectorOfInts = Interprocess::vector<int, ShmAllocator<int>>(intAllocator);

    {
        const auto z = ShmString("aaaaaaaa", stringAllocator);
        vectorOfStrings.push_back(z);
        vectorOfInts.push_back(7);
    }
    {
        const auto z = ShmString("ccccccccccccccccccccccc", stringAllocator);
        vectorOfStrings.push_back(z);
    }
    {
        const auto z = ShmString("bbbb", stringAllocator);
        vectorOfStrings.push_back(z);
    }

    assert(std::strcmp(vectorOfStrings.at(0).c_str(), "aaaaaaaa") == 0);
    assert(std::strcmp(vectorOfStrings.at(1).c_str(), "ccccccccccccccccccccccc") == 0);
    assert(std::strcmp(vectorOfStrings.at(2).c_str(), "bbbb\xFF\xFF\xFF\xC0") == 0); // value received
    assert(std::strcmp(vectorOfStrings.at(2).c_str(), "bbbb") == 0); // value expected
}
```

Comment: What are `ShmString` and `ShmAllocator`? Please show a [mre]

Comment: Do not remove `#include` directives or any other necessary lines from the source.

Answer (score 2):

A lot depends on your type declarations. Assuming:

```
#include <boost/interprocess/containers/string.hpp>
#include <boost/interprocess/containers/vector.hpp>
#include <boost/interprocess/managed_shared_memory.hpp>

namespace Interprocess = boost::interprocess;
using Segment          = Interprocess::managed_shared_memory;
using SMgr             = Segment::segment_manager;
template <typename T>
using ShmAllocator = boost::interprocess::allocator<T, SMgr>;
using ShmString    = Interprocess::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>,
                                             ShmAllocator<char>>;
template <typename T>
using ShmVector = Interprocess::vector<T, ShmAllocator<T>>;
```

I do see your results as well. However, rewriting the asserts like this:

```
assert(vectorOfStrings.at(0) == "aaaaaaaa");
assert(vectorOfStrings.at(1) == "ccccccccccccccccccccccc");
assert(vectorOfStrings.at(2) == "bbbb");                 // value expected
```

Makes them just pass. So in short,

```
assert(vectorOfStrings.at(0) == "aaaaaaaa");
assert(vectorOfStrings.at(1) == "ccccccccccccccccccccccc");
assert(vectorOfStrings.at(2) == "bbbb");

std::string huh = vectorOfStrings.at(2).c_str();
assert(huh == "bbbb"); // huh

std::string fine = vectorOfStrings.at(2);
assert(fine == "bbbb"); // fine
```

As far as I can tell, this is by design. I cannot find a documented guarantee that NUL-terminator is included in [`boost::container::basic_string`](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_78_0/doc/html/boost/container/basic_string.html).

That is, even though `c_str()` (and `data()`) are specified *exactly* like the standard library does:

[image]

The `operator[]` and `at` are *NOT*: Compare Boost's:

[image]

Clearly, it's just **illegal** to look at `operator[size()]`, whereas the standard library has always contained the guarantee: [Does std::string::c_str() always return a null-terminated string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12697788/does-stdstringc-str-always-return-a-null-terminated-string/12697815#12697815)

> Returns: `*(begin() + pos)` if `pos < size()`, **otherwise a reference to an
> object of type `T` with value `charT()`**

---

In short, stick to C++. If you want efficient comparisons just use `string_view`, `std::less<>` etc. which Boost fully supports.

Also, I can't help but notice that it is *very weird* to have the elements of the vectors allocated in shared memory, but not the containers themselves.

Here's my simplified take fixing some of these issues:

**[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/b7bab77165389de6)**

```
#undef NDEBUG
#include <boost/container/scoped_allocator.hpp>
#include <boost/interprocess/containers/string.hpp>
#include <boost/interprocess/containers/vector.hpp>
#include <boost/interprocess/managed_shared_memory.hpp>
#include <boost/interprocess/managed_mapped_file.hpp> // for COLIRU
using namespace std::string_view_literals;

namespace bip = boost::interprocess;
namespace Shared {
    //using Segment = bip::managed_shared_memory;
    using Segment = bip::managed_mapped_file; // for COLIRU

    template <typename T>
    using Alloc = boost::container::scoped_allocator_adaptor<
        boost::interprocess::allocator<T, Segment::segment_manager>>;

    using String = bip::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, Alloc<char>>;

    template <typename T> using Vector = bip::vector<T, Alloc<T>>;
} // namespace Shared

int main()
{
    using Strings = Shared::Vector<Shared::String>;
    using Ints    = Shared::Vector<int>;
    auto shm = Shared::Segment(bip::open_or_create, "test_memory", 1024 * 1024);

    auto& strings = *shm.find_or_construct<Strings>("strings")(shm.get_segment_manager());
    auto& ints    = *shm.find_or_construct<Ints>("ints")(shm.get_segment_manager());

    strings.emplace_back("aaaaaaaa");
    ints.emplace_back(7);
    strings.emplace_back("ccccccccccccccccccccccc");
    strings.emplace_back("bbbb");

    assert(strings.at(0) == "aaaaaaaa");
    assert(strings.at(1) == "ccccccccccccccccccccccc");
    assert(strings.at(2) == "bbbb");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your answer.

The problem is in null-terminated char

```cpp
   //! <b>Returns</b>: Returns a pointer to a null-terminated array of characters 
   //!   representing the string's contents. For any string s it is guaranteed 
   //!   that the first s.size() characters in the array pointed to by s.c_str() 
   //!   are equal to the character in s, and that s.c_str()[s.size()] is a null 
   //!   character. Note, however, that it not necessarily the first null character. 
   //!   Characters within a string are permitted to be null. 
   const CharT* c_str() const 
   {  return detail::get_pointer(this->priv_addr()); }
```

Most importand words:

```
Note, however, that it not necessarily the first null character
```

We can not compare array of chars or convert boost::interprocess::string to std::string using .c_str()

We need to use:

```
assert(std::string{ strings.at(2) } == "bbbb");
```

Comment: This explanation makes no sense at all. There is clearly no NUL character inside "bbbb". That comment is confusing, did you get it from `boost::container::basic_string::c_str()`? Because I have actual screenshots from the documentation which should be generated from that very comment and they do not seem to match. I cannot find what you posted  in the Boost source code.

Comment: Besides, [SO] is not a forum, responding to answers should be done using comments. Welcome to [SO]!

Comment: In fact that comment seems to have never been a part of the Boost Container library since at least 2007 (as `git grep --all -i 'necessarily'` clearly shows). Finally, `std::string { strings.at() }` forces an unnecessary dynamic allocation, instead you can write `strings.at(2) == "bbbb"` which will be much more efficient.

Comment: I found this comment at old version of boost library:
https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_47_0/boost/interprocess/containers/container/string.hpp

Comment: How old? Older than 2007?!

Comment: boost 1.47 was released in 2011

Comment: You mean you got it from 1.47.0? Oh wow. Boost Container didn't even exist back then. And `basic_string` was actually part of the Interprocess library. Yeah, citing docs from that version is... probably not very helpful. (I had just looked at the raw git history for the Boost Container library, which does show a version from 2007 coming from SVN.)

Comment: Yeah, after 1.47 version this comments disappears, why? I don't know, but this rule is actual up to the latest version.

Comment: The whole file doesn't exist anymore. Boost Container became it's own library. "This rule"? What rule? And why do you think it is actual, since the documentation doesn't state or, even implying the opposite?