# DeleteFile() not working

Tags: c++, c, winapi

I was trying the `DeleteFile()` function, and I wrote the program below.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <windows.h>
using namespace std;
int main(){
    FILE * filetxt;
    // creat a file
    filetxt = fopen("C:\\Users\\Thomas\\Desktop\\filetxt.txt", "w");

    // delete the file 
    if (DeleteFile("\\\\.\\C:\\Users\\Thomas\\Desktop\\filetxt.txt") != 0){
        cout<<"success";
    }else{
        cout<<"fail";
    }
    cin;
}
```

But the program didn't work as it was supposed to. The file created wasn't deleted.

The output is:

```
fail
```

Comment: That's because you have opened that file. You should close that file before attempting to delete it

Comment: Why didn't you call `GetLastError` to see why the file deletion failed?

Comment: Try to add `fclose();` before the line `"// delete the file"`

Comment: > The DeleteFile function fails if an application attempts to delete a file that has other handles open for normal I/O or as a memory-mapped file (FILE_SHARE_DELETE must have been specified when other handles were opened).

Comment: I'm surprised the \\.\ path notation works with the non-Unicode version of DeleteFile.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You opened the file with `fopen` and you called `DeleteFile` *before* closing it with `fclose`.

As you can read from [`DeleteFile` MSDN documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/desktop/aa363915(v=vs.85).aspx):

> The **DeleteFile** function fails if an application attempts to delete
>   a file that has other handles open for normal I/O or as a
>   memory-mapped file (**FILE_SHARE_DELETE** must have been specified
>   when other handles were opened).

Note also that, on failure, you can call `GetLastError` after `DeleteFile` to get an error code with more information about the cause of the failure.

Comment: Answering a question about a sharing violation without even mentioning sharing is incomplete at best. You don't *have* to close a file before deleting it. You just have to make sure that it is opened using an appropriate sharing mode. Not opening a file is equivalent to sharing it for anything, but that's just a special case of the more generic issue: Making sure to not provoke a sharing violation.

Comment: @IInspectable Instead of giving judgements like "wildly incomplete" to other people's answers, I encourage you to write your own answer. Wait, [I've found an answer of yours](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19624153/1629821) on converting from std::string to CString in Unicode projects that doesn't mention code pages and encoding for the std::string. I guess it's still "wildly incomplete", but whatever...

Comment: Ah dammit. Gotta -1 this one, just because it's you.

Comment: @IInspectable Ah dammit. I returned the favor on your other answer, just because it's you. You are feee to down-vote every answer of mine, but I still think this one (while not perfect) is a valid good answer that does NOT deserve down-votes. Stackoverflow will be a better community when people start to understand to be more humble and more respectful of other people's efforts and time.

Comment: Be humble in accepting that [voting is important](http://stackoverflow.com/help/why-vote), even if you don't like it.

Comment: I do agree that _serious_ voting is important. An answer can be up voted, down voted, or none of these. I think down voting is for really bad answers, and I think this one is not. As I said, it's not perfect, but I believe it doesn't deserve a down vote. Anyway, as I already wrote, you are free to down vote every answer of mine, if you wish :) I won't return the favor, as I have better things to do, and I also think you contributed good answers that deserve up votes. That said, if you really think this answer deserves a down vote, I respect your right to act accordingly.