# C++ creating CString from std::string fails

Tags: c++, visual-studio, mfc, c-strings, stdstring

In my MFC based application this code:

```
std::string stdString("MappingName");
std::cout << "as String: " << stdString << std::endl;
CString cString(stdString.c_str());
std::cout << "as CString: " << cString << std::endl;
```

Produces this output:

```
as String: MappingName
as CString: 01DEA060
```

The value of the `CString` is different every time I run it, but the length seems to be constant. Some other results are `042219B0` and `042C4378`.

I've tried every variation discussed in [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19616828/how-to-convert-stdstring-to-cstring-in-unicode-project), with the results being the same. I've also tried to change the Character Set in the Visual Studio project from *Use Unicode Character Set* to *Use Multi-Byte Character Set*, again with no effect.

What could be the reason the conversion fails?

Edit:
More tests show that the value of the `std::string` doesn't seem to make a difference:

```
tmp as String: The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog
tmp as CString: 00EAAF88
```

I've also set the Character Set to *Not Set* which didn't help either.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem is printing not conversion.

`CString` can implicilty convert to `TCHAR const*`.  When built with unicode enabled, this is `wchar_t const*`.

`std::cout` has no `wchar_t const*` overload for `<<`.  It does have a `void const*` overload.

The void pointer overload prints a pointer address in hex.

Cast to `CStringA` before printing:

```
std::cout << "as CString: " << static_cast<CStringA>(cString) << std::endl;
```

Or print using `wcout`.

Comment: _"Cast to CStringA"_ ... or simply create a `CStringA` variable in the first place to avoid the cast.

Comment: Especially, since the cast invokes a *lossy* conversion. It may be safe when round-tripping from ANSI to Unicode back to ANSI, but in general, it isn't.

Comment: @iinsp it is the best cout can handle, however.

Comment: Presumably, `cout` is just used as an example. It's not the real code.

Comment: @iinsp some other interface with `void const*` and `char const*` APIs that interprets the void case as a pointer address interpreted in hex as a string value thus getting confused by the `wchar_t const*` conversion operator of `CString` could, I guess, be the real problem.  But I doubt it.  This question, as I read it, is about the narrow collision of Microsofts implicit cast to wide character and the permissive interface of cout streaming causing a confusing resulting behaviour.

Answer (score 3):

The issue is a combination of two aspects:

- Mixture of string types with explicit encoding (`std::string`) and generic-text mapping (`CString` vs. `CStringA`/`CStringW`).
- `CString`'s ability to convert between encodings through [conversion c'tors](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/atl-mfc-shared/reference/cstringt-class#cstringt).

The `std::string` converted to the `CString` just fine, presumably constructing a `CStringW` object. Since there is no `operator<<` overload for the `std::ostream` that takes a `wchar_t const*` (which `CStringW` [implicitly converts to](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/atl-mfc-shared/reference/csimplestringt-class#operator_pcxstr)), it merely prints the address, matching the generic `void const*` overload.

The solution here is to take the generic-text mappings out of the picture, and construct a `CString` specialization matching the source encoding (ANSI for `std::string`, i.e. `CStringA`):

```
std::string stdString("MappingName");
std::cout << "as String: " << stdString << std::endl;
CStringA cString(stdString.c_str());
std::cout << "as CString: " << cString.GetString() << std::endl;
```

To get notified about implicit conversions when constructing `CString`s, you can `#define` the `_CSTRING_DISABLE_NARROW_WIDE_CONVERSION` proprocessor symbol. This will in turn generate compiler errors in case you are trying to invoke any of the conversion c'tors.