# std::string `s` is cast to char* via `&s[0]` - how/why does this work?

Tags: c++, stdstring

I came across [this way](https://github.com/ros-drivers/prosilica_driver/blob/hydro-devel/prosilica_camera/src/libprosilica/prosilica.cpp#L442) of using a std::string to receive a buffer.

Here it is simplified:

```cpp
error_enum_t  get_fn(char*, unsigned long, unsigned long*);

void getStringValuedAttribute(std::string &value)
{
  if (value.size() == 0) {
    value.resize(32);
  }

  unsigned long actual_size;
  get_fn(&value[0], value.size(), &actual_size));

  if (actual_size >= value.size()) {
    value.resize(actual_size + 1);
    get_fn(&value[0], value.size(), &actual_size);
  }
}
```

After some digging on repl.it, I see that `&value[0]` is type `char *`, which I guess makes sense, because `value[0]` would have to be `char`. But it seems like this is giving direct access to `value`'s buffer. Is that all that is going on here, or is there more wizardry afoot?

I tried digging into the source of `basic_string.h` and I see `_M_local_buf`, but there is a ton of template action going on and this is not my strong suit.

If I had to wager a guess, `value[]` is leveraging `operator []` overloading to get access to a pointer reference to the start of the internal buffer, which is compatible with `char *`, so the `get_fn` is able to treat it like a vanilla buffer.

Is my assessment correct? Is this a wise idiom, nay, is it even safe?

Comment: That's a hack. Instead, use [`.data()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/data)

Comment: "*it seems like this is giving direct access to value's buffer*" - that is exactly what it is doing. Though, technically, this wasn't officially legal until C++11, but it was common practice as most *implementations* allowed it. "*If I had to wager a guess, ... Is my assessment correct?*" - yes.

Comment: @scohe001 It's not a hack and `.data()` returns `const char*` which you would be casting with `const_cast` and that is an awful hack.

Comment: TIL: "starting in c++17, str.data() returns a char* instead of const char*"  https://stackoverflow.com/a/54872471/3988037. Also, according to cplusplus.com, "Both string::data and string::c_str are synonyms and return the same value." as of C++11.

Answer (score 1):

> this is giving direct access to value's buffer

Correct (C++11).

Correct in practice (C++99).

As commented by @remy-lebeau and explained in a (also mentioned) [very similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1986966/does-s0-point-to-contiguous-characters-in-a-stdstring): before C++11 this was not standardized.

You can see in [this reference](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/data/) that for C++98 `std::string::data`

> Returns a pointer to an array that contains the same sequence of characters as the characters that make up the value of the string object.

So, *in theory* you could have a C++98 implementation that returns a copy of this `std::string` state. But in practice, as said, implementations allowed it to be the real string data.

While for C++11 `std::string::data` the differences are:

> Returns a pointer to an array that contains a null-terminated sequence of characters (i.e., a C-string) representing the current value of the string object.
>
> This array includes the same sequence of characters that make up the value of the string object plus an additional terminating null-character ('\0') at the end.
>
> The pointer returned points to the internal array currently used by the string object to store the characters that conform its value.
>
> Both string::data and string::c_str are synonyms and return the same value.

Now more consistent.

> Is this a wise idiom, nay, is it even safe?

It is safe, from C++11 on it's a 100% safe.

I think, as they're basically the same, the wisest would be to use `std::string::data` because it's more **legible** and keep semantics ok.

Comment: This has been very enlightening to this here C++ greenhorn. Most of the stuff I deal with is ROS related, and enforcing `-std=c++11` minimum seems to be a matter of course in general. But it's good to know that the interface changes in subtle ways before 11.